# How can I use a nested type belonging to a templated class in another template function in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, inner-classes

I'm setting up a function that initializes tuples based on a tuple type and a functor struct `For` that has a size_t template argument `INDEX` to retain the compile-time index. This functor may also depend on other template arguments `T...`. Because of this the functors exist within other structures (`TClass` in this example) that hold these template arguments.

The initialization function (called `Bar` here) has a `template<std::size_t> class` template argument to ensure that the used class actually can store the index.

While the design I've come up with works fine when I call it from a non-template function, it does not compile if the template `T2` of a function does determine the template parameter of the wrapper `TClass`.

Here is the definition of the functor `For` wrapped inside `TClass`:

```cpp
#include <cstdlib>

template <typename T> struct TClass {

    template<std::size_t INDEX> struct For {

        void operator()() {}
    };      
};
```

And here are the function calls i want to use:

```cpp
template <template<std::size_t> class FOR> void bar() {
    //...
} 

template <typename T> void foo() {  
   bar<TClass<T>::For>(); //Does not compile
}

int main() {

    bar<TClass<int>::For>(); //Works
    foo<int>(); 

    return 0;
}
```

The compiler output for the faulty `foo`-call is:

```
error: dependent-name ‘TClass<T>::For’ is parsed as a non-type, but instantiation yields a type
    Bar<TClass<T>::For>(); //Does not compile
```

I know that dependent type names usually have to be preceded by a `typename` but this is also not necessary for the first `bar`-call. I assumed it was because the template argument can only be interpreted as a type. So I thought that maybe `typename` would result in correct compilation but if I change `foo` to

```cpp
template <typename T> void foo() {  
   bar<typename TClass<T>::For>(); //Does not compile
}
```

I get:

```
error: ‘typename TClass<int>::For’ names ‘template<long unsigned int INDEX> struct TClass<int>::For’, which is not a type
    Bar<typename TClass<T>::For>(); //Does not compile
```

I've also come up with a design where the `()`-operator of `TClass` depends on the template `INDEX` which also works fine because it is not necessary to use nested types anymore. It looks like this:

```cpp
#include <cstdlib>

template <typename T> struct TClass {

    template<std::size_t INDEX> void operator()() {}
};

template <typename FOR> void bar() {
    //...
} 

template <typename T> void foo() {  
   bar<TClass<T>>(); //Does compile
}
```

Apparently it is not possible to use dependent type names in functions where the template of the type is determined by the function's template parameters, but why? And how do I implement this correctly? To make writing future type checks with type traits easier I would prefer it if I can use a functor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler cannot know that `TClass<T>::For` refers to a template at the first stage of template instantiation. It needs a bit of help with `template` keyword. Fix:

```
template <typename T> void foo() {  
    bar<TClass<T>::template For>(); 
}
```

Comment: Given the error message the compiler clearly *does* know, just not soon enough. Even that is solvable but adds sufficient complexity that the language accommodates compiler writers by forcing programmers to be explicit.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Added _at the first stage of template instantiation_ for you.

Comment: @MichaelVeksler I am able to reproduce the original error and fix it. See https://ideone.com/8HuXan

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Thank you. I somehow assumed that we can only use `template` in conjunction with `typename`. So the `bar`-call in main works because we can infer that `For` must be a templated type because we have complete information about all templates?

Comment: @StefanGroth Yes, in `main` it is known that `TClass<int>::For` is a template. Whereas in a template `TClass<T>::For` could refer to anything during the first phase of template instantiation, depending on `T` and `TClass<T>` specialization.